# attempt to index local 'q' (a nil value)

Tags: mysql, lua, null

I ran this code and it gave me an error ".../mysql.lua:32: attempt to index local 'q' (a nil value)"

```
 function _MySQL.Query(query, callback)
    local q = localDB:query(query)
    q:start()
    q:wait()
    if q:error() == "" then
        return q:getData(), true
    else
        return nil, false
    end
end
```

Comment: What library for lua are you using to run along side this? From the looks of it the query function returns nothing hence you get that q is a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this: `local localDB = nil;`

Now error disapeard but i think it's from another mistake.
Created a new better Question for better answers.